# "Parent Role id ‘G1’ does not exist" error message is displayed on login as admin

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

On login to backend as admin in magento

"Parent Role id ‘G1’ does not exist" error message is displayed on login as admin

Can any one tell me what to do for this error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try run this query:

```
insert into admin_role values(1,0,1,1,'G',0,'Administrator');


insert into admin_rule values (8,1,'all',null,0,'G','allow');
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by updating the tree_level on all Users to "2" in the database...

`UPDATE admin_role SET tree_level = 2 WHERE role_type = "U";`

Then I cleared my Magento cache and sessions and was able to log in successfully.

This fix was suggested by [this solution](http://www.fly2mars-media.de/seoblog/magento/magento-parent-role-id-g4-does-not-exist-or-other-ids-101936/).  It also recommended making a change to the core code, but so far that hasn't been needed in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the cache fixed things for me.

```
echo flush_all | nc localhost 11211
rm -rf var/cache
```

Answer (score 0):

- Check the "role_id" with the respective "resource_id" in "admin_rule" table.
- Assign the "role_id" with the "all" resources as a "parent_id" in "admin_role" table, also set the "tree_level" to "2" in "admin_role" table and You're done.